# DocumentRoot not setting the proper webroot, apache

Tags: apache, document-root, virtual-hosts

My virtual hosts webroot doesn't appear to be pointing where i want it to go.

Here is my virtual host

```
VirtualHost *.80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myhost
    ServerName myhost
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/myhost/apache_error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

And my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       myhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

However when i visit -> myhost

I get the directory /var/www and i can see the /html folder sitting there.

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you miss `<` when pasting `VirtualHost *.80>` or is that how  your apache conf file is?

Comment: I missed it in the paste.